# Want to use a variable outside the scope of ngFor

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, scope, ngfor

`<mat-select [(ngModel)]="e1Instance" (selectionChange)="e1InstanceChanged(item)"> <mat-option *ngFor="let item of entities"  value={{item.name}} >{{item.name}}</mat-option></mat-select>`
Hi Community,
This is how I want to use the code...
I want to use the item variable on first line in (SELECTIONCHANGE)
If i move my ngFor above it is going to create a chaos making multiple mat-selects.
Any Suggestions

I want to use the item variable on first line in (SELECTIONCHANGE)
If i move my ngFor above it is going to create a chaos making multiple mat-selects.
Any Suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that I found:

- Create a new function of onClick on Mat-Option.
- Create that function in your TS file.
- Save the value of current entity in some other variable.
- Pass that variable in SELECTIONCHANGE.